# Array compairing function returning two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
    var array1 = [
    [{"home":{"homename":"KFC Komarno","homepoint":"1"},"away":{"awayname":"Podbrezova","awaypoint":"0"}}],
    
    [{"home":{"homename":"Kazicbarcika","homepoint":"0"},"away":{"awayname":"Soroksar","awaypoint":"1"}},
{"home":{"homename":"Szentlőrinc","homepoint":"0"},"away":{"awayname":"Ajka","awaypoint":"1"}}]
    ]
    


   var array2 = [
    [{"home":{"homename":"KFC Komarno","homepoint":"1"},"away":{"awayname":"Podbrezova","awaypoint":"0"}}],
    
    [{"home":{"homename":"Kazicbarcika","homepoint":"0"},"away":{"awayname":"Soroksar","awaypoint":"1"}},
{"home":{"homename":"Szentlőrinc","homepoint":"1"},"away":{"awayname":"Ajka","awaypoint":"1"}}]
    ]
```

In both variables the second array is containing two arrays. In the second one i changed the homepoint: to 1 at Szentlőrinc, so a compairing function should return as changed array only the third one.

```
{"home":{"homename":"Szentlőrinc","homepoint":"1"},"away":{"awayname":"Ajka","awaypoint":"1"}}]
```

Here is the script:

```
getChanges = function(oldArray, newArray) {
    var changes, i, item, j, len;
    if (JSON.stringify(oldArray) === JSON.stringify(newArray)) {
      return false;
    }
    changes = [];
    for (i = j = 0, len = newArray.length; j < len; i = ++j) {
      item = newArray[i];
      if (JSON.stringify(item) !== JSON.stringify(oldArray[i])) {
        changes.push(item);
      }
    }
    return changes;
  };
  var goals = getChanges(array1, array2);
  if (goals.length > 0) {
    console.log(goals);}
```

But instead of returning only that one, the function is returning the whole :

```
[{"home":{"homename":"Kazicbarcika","homepoint":"0"},"away":{"awayname":"Soroksar","awaypoint":"1"}},{"home":{"homename":"Szentlőrinc","homepoint":"1"},"away":{"awayname":"Ajka","awaypoint":"1"}}]
```

What am i missing here? is there any solution? please help

Comment: Could you explain your issue with a less complex array?

Comment: **the second array is containing two arrays** It contains two objects, not two arrays.

Comment: So if var array1 =[[{data=0}], [[{data=0}, {data=0}]]     //////      array2 =[[{data=0}], [[{data=1}, {data=0}]]                             the script is returning [[{data=1}, {data=0}]]   from array2   because  {data=1} is changed, but it should return only {data=1}, not the whole object which is containing this array. How should i change the function to return only that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never comparing the objects inside your sub-arrays, but only the whole arrays themselves, so that's why you are not getting the results you expect.

If you only want to get the element inside the object that changed instead of the whole object, you could use `reduce` (I was hugely inspired by the other answer to be fair):

```js
const array1 = [
  [
    {
      home: { homename: "KFC Komarno", homepoint: "1" },
      away: { awayname: "Podbrezova", awaypoint: "0" }
    }
  ],

  [
    {
      home: { homename: "Kazicbarcika", homepoint: "0" },
      away: { awayname: "Soroksar", awaypoint: "1" }
    },
    {
      home: { homename: "Szentlőrinc", homepoint: "0" },
      away: { awayname: "Ajka", awaypoint: "1" }
    }
  ]
];

const array2 = [
  [
    {
      home: { homename: "KFC Komarno", homepoint: "1" },
      away: { awayname: "Podbrezova", awaypoint: "0" }
    }
  ],

  [
    {
      home: { homename: "Kazicbarcika", homepoint: "0" },
      away: { awayname: "Soroksar", awaypoint: "1" }
    },
    {
      home: { homename: "Szentlőrinc", homepoint: "1" },
      away: { awayname: "Ajka", awaypoint: "1" }
    }
  ]
];

function getChanges(oldArray, newArray) {
  return newArray.reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
    if (cur.home.homepoint !== oldArray[index].home.homepoint) {
      acc = [...acc, { home: cur.home }];
    }
    if (cur.away.awaypoint !== oldArray[index].away.awaypoint) {
      acc = [...acc, { away: cur.away }];
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

const goals = getChanges(array1.flat(), array2.flat());

console.log(goals);
```

Previous answer:

```js
const array1 = [
  [
    {
      home: { homename: "KFC Komarno", homepoint: "1" },
      away: { awayname: "Podbrezova", awaypoint: "0" }
    }
  ],

  [
    {
      home: { homename: "Kazicbarcika", homepoint: "0" },
      away: { awayname: "Soroksar", awaypoint: "1" }
    },
    {
      home: { homename: "Szentlőrinc", homepoint: "0" },
      away: { awayname: "Ajka", awaypoint: "1" }
    }
  ]
];

const array2 = [
  [
    {
      home: { homename: "KFC Komarno", homepoint: "1" },
      away: { awayname: "Podbrezova", awaypoint: "0" }
    }
  ],

  [
    {
      home: { homename: "Kazicbarcika", homepoint: "0" },
      away: { awayname: "Soroksar", awaypoint: "1" }
    },
    {
      home: { homename: "Szentlőrinc", homepoint: "1" },
      away: { awayname: "Ajka", awaypoint: "1" }
    }
  ]
];

const getChanges = function (oldArray, newArray) {
  let changes = [];
  if (JSON.stringify(oldArray) === JSON.stringify(newArray)) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < newArray[i].length; j++) {
      if (JSON.stringify(newArray[i][j]) !== JSON.stringify(oldArray[i][j])) {
        changes.push(newArray[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return changes;
};
const goals = getChanges(array1, array2);
if (goals.length > 0) {
  console.log(goals);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! couldn't figure it out by myself how to solve it

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < newArray[i].length; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < newArray[i][j].length; k++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(newArray[i][j][k]) !== JSON.stringify(oldArray[i][j][k])) {
          changes.push(newArray[i][j][k]);
        }}}};                 i tried to modify your code like this, i hoped that it will show that particular array where the change was, so i mean that team, but it is not working, what do you think, is it possible to add another level? for example to get this: away: { awayname: "Soroksar", awaypoint: "1" }

Comment: @Samy93 Well, you _could_ do that: `for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < newArray[i].length; j++) {
      for (const idx in newArray[i][j]) {
        if (
          JSON.stringify(newArray[i][j][idx]) !==
          JSON.stringify(oldArray[i][j][idx])
        )
          changes.push({ [idx]: newArray[i][j][idx] });
      }
    }
  }` but the code is getting pretty ugly at this point to be honest.
Anyway, the other answer gave me an idea to do what you want, I will edit mine.

Comment: I owe you with a beer! thanks a lot for the updated version

Answer (score 0):

The comparison function seems way too complex.

A solution is to loop over the games in the newArray, and compare each game entry with the corresponding one in the oldArray. If the `homepoint` or `awaipoint` is different, we should **filter** this game entry.

1. Flatten the nested arrays the make the comparison more easy
2. Filter non-matching games

See the following code snippet, which is using the 2 arrays provided in your question.

```js
const flattenedOldArray = array1.flat()
const flattenedNewArray = array2.flat()

function filterChangedGames(newArray, oldArray) {
  return newArray.filter((newGame, index) => {
    const oldGame = oldArray[index]
    return (newGame.home.homepoint !== oldGame.home.homepoint) || (newGame.away.awaypoint !== oldGame.away.awaypoint)
  })
}

const changedGames = filterChangedGames(flattenedNewArray, flattenedOldArray)
```

PS: In this code-snippet, [Array.prototype.flat()](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_flat) isn't supported by Internet Explorer 11 and some older browsers. If you need to support older browsers, make sure to use code transpilers/compilers like [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io).

Comment: Thanks, works like charm! theoretically what do you think, which function is faster with bigger data?

Comment: You're welcome! It's better to NOT use JSON.stringify to compare objects/arrays since the order of object keys isn't 100% guaranteed. "{a: 1, b: 2}" is not equal to "{b: 2, a: 1}" when using JSON.stringify.

Comment: For performance, it depends. JSON.stringify on large objects/arrays can be much slower than looping over the array and comparing some values (e.g. hompoint & awaypoint). The performance in this example seems marginal. For me personally, the readability of the code is more important in this case. I personally think this solution is more readable than the nested loops with JSON.stringify.

Comment: Okay, i got it :D solving to return only the team and the point where it was a change is possible from your code?

Comment: Not without some additions to the games in the Array. Do you have a Back-end or is this a Front-end only app?  The games should have a unique ID for the solution that I've got in mind.

Comment: Front end only, that data is all i get

Comment: Is the games array hard-coded or created (e.g. with a form) in your app?

Comment: Scraped, than pushed in array with map

Comment: Is there something unique you can scrape and use it as an id? Ideally, each game-Object should have an id. So { id, home, away }

Comment: Will look at it, thanks for the tips and help ;)